# Hover not reliable in a relative hierarchy using CSS rotation

Tags: css, 3d, hover, css-position

I'm trying to create a online card game, using pure HTML/CSS.
I created a relative hierarchy of objects and I want the user to interact with them.
Probleme is, with CSS rotations (transform: rotateX, transform-style: preserve-3d), hover is not reliable.

Here's a simplified version of what it looks like :
http://jsfiddle.net/qLg9u51e/1/

Here are the main elements :

```
.container {
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.tile {
  position: relative;
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
}

.object:hover {
  background: red
}
```

I am expecting the orange object to be red while the mouse is hovering it, but as you can see, that's not always the case. It's a weird behaviour and I do not fully understand it.

By removing either rotateX, preserve-3d or the relative property, the hover property works correctly, but I need these elements.

Why am I doing wrong here ? And if you don't know how to solve my problem, do you know why CSS is acting like this ?

Comment: what browser? in chrome it's fine by the way, the jsfiddle is different from the code posted here

Comment: Oops sorry I posted the wrong Jsfiddle. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `row` was overlapping the `object` at some points (not all, which is a bit confusing!).

Adding `.row { pointer-events: none; }`and `.object { pointer-events: all; }` fixes the problem:

```css
.master {
  perspective: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
    transform: rotateX(50deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.row {
  width: 200px;
  background: darkgray;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tile {
  height: 150px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  background: #505050;
  position: relative;
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.object:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="object"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's not ideal since I can't quite pinpoint the root cause, but it works in the meantime!